# Askinu Seudasa and Azamer Bishvachin before Kiddush

Tags: shabbat, song-poetry, meal-seudah, kiddush

There is a variety of placement in siddurim which include Askinu Seudasa and Azamer Bishvachin.  Some (Tefila Yeshara, Artscroll if memory serves correctly) put both before Kiddush.  Some (Tehilas Hashem) put Askinu Seudasa before Kiddush and Azamer Bishvachin is placed after Hamotzi as a zemer.  I have also heard that some say both as zmiros, although I haven't seen a siddur which evidences this practice.

There also seems to sometimes be a variance in practice between evening Kiddush and morning Kiddush.

What are the reasons behind the differing placements?  Which groups follow which opinion?

Comment: @msh210 Good point!  I neglected it because there's no Kiddush, but there's still a question of before or after hamotzi.

Comment: Some do say _kidush_ at _s'uda sh'lishis_ (though I **think** those who do so do so after they start to eat).

Comment: @msh210 interesting - any source or association with a particular minhag?

Comment: Well, for one thing, it's in bentschers (with the relevant text; it has no _b'racha_ besides _hagafen_ (or _hagefen_) and is otherwise similar to the morning _kidush_). I believe some _chasidim_ do it. I know nothing further.

Comment: @msh210 huh, I never noticed.  I'll have to take a look when I get home.

Comment: As a mere data point to the "kiddush" at seuda shlishit, Bostoner chassidim do this.  It is done during the meal, and all that is said is the bracha of hagafen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I heard it said by R' Eluzer Kenig shlita, the Rav of the Breslev community of Tzfas, that one recites Askinu Seudasa and Azamer Bishvachin after making hamotzi and eating a kezayis of bread.

On the subject, I was told by a talmid of R' Kenig that the Arizal originally composed these zmiros to be recited during the meal.  The practice today in Breslev is still to recite them there.

The real question, then, is when they got moved to various places before the meal.

Comment: +1. Who is R' Eluzer Kenig?

Comment: He is a leading Breslov Rabbi in Tzfas. Did Yoel just "answer" his own question?

Comment: @msh210 The Rav of the Breslev community of Tzfas.  His father was R' Gedalia Kenig ztz'l, who was a talmid of R' Avraham Sternhartz ztz'l, the great-grandson of Reb Noson of Breslev zy'a.

Comment: @mochinrechavim it took me two months but I found the answer! :)

Comment: @mochinrechavim http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/306/if-i-know-the-answer-to-a-question